# Unreachble catch block java exercise

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I'm doing some java exercise for an exam and I have a problem in some of them, like this:
This is the code:

```
public class A1 {

public static void main(String [] argv)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        m();
        System.out.print(1);
    }
    catch( Exception u ) {
        System.out.print(2);
    }
    finally {
        System.out.print(3);
        throw( new MyExc2() );
    }
}
static void m()
        throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.print(4);
    }
    catch( MyExc2 t ) {
        System.out.print(5);
    }
    catch( MyExc1 h ) {
        throw( new MyExc1() );
    }
    catch( Exception b ) {
    }
    finally {
        System.out.print(6);
    }
  }
}
```

and the Exception hierarchy is:

```
class MyExc1 extends Exception { }
class MyExc2 extends Exception { }
class MyExc3 extends MyExc2 { }
```

The compiler give me this error: "Unreachable catch block for MyExc2. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"?
Why is important the fact that is unreachable, can't the compiler just ignore it? (sorry for my poor english, hope you can understand)

Comment: The compiler *could* ignore it but the compiler / the compiler designers chose not to. It alerts the programmer that having unreachable code is bad and almost always an indication of a bug by the programmer.

Comment: Code that *cannot* be executed is generally a development error; it *may* be harmless (in which case it should be removed) but it's *always* misleading.

Comment: @luk2302 ok but it isn't just a warning/alert, they are errors and I can't compile the program, is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, it's normal (otherwise it wouldn't happen).

Comment: There really is no point in arguing this, it is a compiler error, period. Why? Check my comment for the argument or read the given answer. Is it normal? For a java compiler yes, because that is how it is specified to behave - it does not just roll a dice and then decides to throw a warning 50% of the time and an error the other 50%. For other compilers? Maybe not, but that is irrelevant to the java compiler / the question.

Comment: Dead code usually indicates error on programmer side which is most often serious problem since code does **not** do what programmer intends. There are some exceptions from this rule like `if (false){ System.out.println("unreachable but compiles fine"); }` but usually we *want* to get compilation error in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a design choice on the language level.

Unreachable code means: **dead code**. Lines of code that sit there and do nothing. From a technical point of view, they do not matter, the compiler will simply not **compile** them.

But remember that source code is "mainly" written for **human** readers: and human readers have to spend "brain CPU cycles" to read and understand code. So why force humans to invest that energy for dead code?

And worse: it could mislead human readers. People might just glance over some code and draw conclusions on that dead code. For example, they might start looking into the code in the try block, trying to identify where that exception might come from. Or even worse: they do not think about that, but start copying that code around, including the useless try/catch.

And back then, when Java was designed, people put an emphasis on a "clean" language, that results in code that is easy to read and understand, and that makes it hard to do things the wrong way.

It is a trade off, and the language designers decided to do it like this.

Another angle: as a programmer, you always strive to write the **smallest** amount of code that implements a feature, you don't want your code base to turn into a junkyard. And sometimes the compiler can help you achieving that goal.

Answer (score 1):

The code in catch block for `MyExc2` is unreachable, because the `println` method called at `System.out.print(4)` does not declare possibility of throwing the `MyExc2` exception.

Comment: While true this does not answer the question why the compiler errors out instead of e.g. just warning the user.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you asked is more to know why is unreachable, but i am going to leave my pov:

There are some exceptions that are never treated in the body of the method, instead, you throw it just a side of the method like this:

```
    public Object nMethod(nParamType nParamName) throws myExc2 {}
```

Try to solve your excersice in that way, and i sorry as well for the poor english